# How to add save file dialog in plug-in using 3d's max 2016 SDK (C++)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, 3dsmax

I'm currently using 3d's Max 2016 SDK via MV Studio 2012. I've created usual project with Plugin Wizard, it creates panel with text and button (and does many actions inside the code, but that is not the theme).
So, now I want to add some button to activate Windows File Dialog to choose path (folder) and name of .bin-file that will be created afterwards.

I tried to find something in the toolbox at the resource editor but have not succeed.
What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please read this for best results when using this site.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved de-facto. Just used pushbutton and GetSaveFileName function from windows.h header.
For details, read here:
[how to save file with GetSaveFileName in win32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449304/how-to-save-file-with-getsavefilename-in-win32)

Answer (score 2):

As you said, you can use directly winapi to create your dialog, but the aesthetic result of the window should differ a bit from dialog already used in 3dsMax. Autodesk has made a lot of UI controls by themselves (or patched winapi ones) and provide their access in the SDK to have something homogeneous between the application and plugins.

What you are looking for here, is the function named DoMaxSaveAsDialog and should be available in Interface8.

[Interface8 Class Reference](https://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2018/ENU/?guid=__cpp_ref_class_interface8_html)